# Comment JSX code in Sublime and atom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, comments, jsx

Is there any way how to comment a code inside `return` statement in `render` function in React.js (JSX) without curly brackets? It is pretty annoying to write curly brackets everytime you want to comment some piece of code.

Comment: which editor are you using

Comment: If you are using VSCode then you can use `ctrl+shift+a` shortcut to create block comment. [Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing)

Comment: I am using [atom.io](https://atom.io/) at work, and [sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) at home

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like you need to put too many comments, just put the block, you want to comment in  external Component.

Comment: That is still more work to do than just simply write following: `// some commentary`

Answer (score 0):

In sublime you can setting up default comments in the following way

Create an XML file in `Packages/User` called `Comments.tmPreferences` with the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.jsx</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>// </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>{/* </string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string> */}</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>F9BFFF1F-1999-4722-B094-52E8AFD234D1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And after doing this you can set up comments by selecting the block and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+/`. this will wrap your contents within `{/*   */}`

**EDIT:**

You could also make use of package like `JSPrettier` to format your code which will handle comments as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it when I come home and than let you know how it works. But still it seems to me quite complicated, you need to do an extra step (selecting a block and pressing `Ctrl+Shift+/`)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add it to https://github.com/borela/naomi but it required many workarounds, meta scopes and a [plugin](https://github.com/borela/naomi/blob/master/plugin/commands/ToggleJsxComment.py).

The biggest downside is that it won't work for Atom as I used many features that are specific to sublime.