# Commenting out JSX in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx

For months now I've been frustrated by the lack of commenting (command + /) in JSX.  Is this possible?

Comment: What package are you using to provide the JSX syntax?

Comment: in prefs/browse-packages i see `Babel`, `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`, and `JS-Prettier`

Comment: you could read this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064715/commentary-inside-react-render-function-without-curly-brackets/43065934#43065934

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `CTRL` + `Shift` + `/`

Comment: This is not working. Do i need to do something else as well?

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend using [`babel-sublime`](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/) for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3, as you can see [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/262#issuecomment-217784952) there are number of issues with JSX commenting. However it can be achieved, to quote [@zertosh](https://github.com/zertosh):

> Unfortunately there are a combination of issues that make this unfixable. There is no such thing as a JSX comment. You can have JSX expressions (curly braces) with JS comments - but that's babel-sublime faking it as a convenience. That fakery bites you when you try to uncomment - as you've noticed. There's an ambiguity there. Since the curly braces are not part of the comment, Sublime leaves them behind.
>
> An alternative would be to scope the JSX expression curly braces as part of the comment. That could result in themes having issues though. It would look like this:
>
> [image: JSX syntax highlighting]
>
> You can try it yourself with this patch:

```
    diff --git a/JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax b/JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax
    index ec9403e..dffd90e 100644
    --- a/JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax 
    +++ b/JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax 
    @@ -1185,6 +1185,13 @@ contexts:
           scope: invalid.illegal.bad-ampersand.jsx

       jsx-evaluated-code:
    +    - match: \{/\*
    +      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.begin.js
    +      push:
    +        - meta_scope: comment.block.js
    +        - match: \*/\}
    +          scope: punctuation.definition.comment.end.js
    +          pop: true
         - match: \{
           scope: punctuation.section.embedded.begin.jsx
           push:
```

**EDIT**

To implement the patch, simply edit after line 1109 of the [`JavaScript (Babel).sublime-syntax`](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/blob/1f6885f95bceabd6ce1c0b8c2510951fd7ba076d/JavaScript%20(Babel).sublime-syntax#L1109) file by adding the lines below with the plus sign in front of them (+):

```
.....
    scope: invalid.illegal.bad-ampersand.jsx

   jsx-evaluated-code:
+    - match: \{/\*
+      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.begin.js
+      push:
+        - meta_scope: comment.block.js
+        - match: \*/\}
+          scope: punctuation.definition.comment.end.js
+          pop: true
     - match: \{
       scope: punctuation.section.embedded.begin.jsx
       push:
.....
```

Comment: how do i apply the patch?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately commenting in code that has a mix of JS/JSX is not as straight forward as it should, I managed to add it to https://github.com/borela/naomi but it required many workarounds, meta scopes and a [plugin](https://github.com/borela/naomi/blob/master/plugin/commands/ToggleJsxComment.py).

Answer (score 0):

There is no esasy way on doing this in just one shortcut, but yes in two

you select HTML code you want to comment
then you type character {, so sublime text will surround all selected area,
then ctrl + shift + 7 for block code, individual comments do not work for this, still, you might use bock comment for a single line

Use case

```
//1st step
<IndividualStep></IndividualStep>
```

```
//2nd step
{<IndividualStep></IndividualStep>}
```

```
//3th step
{/*<IndividualStep></IndividualStep>*/}
```

There you are, it works for any HTML block on JSX